# What is wrong with this tiny python program?

Tags: python-3.x

I'm completely new to python and have been trying to experiment with things that I've been learning as I learn them. One of these things is using if statements. As you can see, when you run the program and input the correct answer which is 11 you will get a "yes!" message. Or else you will get a message that tells you the number you input plus 33 is not 44. However, when I input the correct answer (11) it still tells me that 11 + 33 is not 44. Curious why this is & if I am missing something?

```
num_in = input("what + 33 is 44?: ")
set_num = str(22 + 11)

if(num_in + set_num == str(44)):
    print(" Yes!")
else:
    print(num_in + " + " + set_num + " is not 44.")
```

Comment: Since both `num_in` and `set_num` are strings, `num_in + set_num` is string concatenation, which is `"1133"`. Don't convert numbers to strings unless you have to. Your problem can be fixed by getting rid of `str()` calls and converting the input to a number i.e. `int(input(...))`.

Comment: How about you print out `num_in + set_num` and see what value it has?

Comment: @Selcuk I thought num_in was a string input and set_num was an int? and that you can't concatenate strings and integers? what would you do differently?

Comment: No, `set_num` is a string because you explicitly convert it to a string using `str(22 + 11)`. and you can't concatenate strings and integers in Python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, num_in and set_num are strings, and string concatenation doesn't follow math. Here, let num_in is "11" and set_num is "33" then set_num+num_in is "3311" which is not str(44), just take int values
Edited code:

```
num_in = int(input("what + 33 is 44?: "))
set_num = 33

if(num_in + set_num == 44):
    print(" Yes!")
else:
    print(f"{num_in} + {set_num}  is not 44.")
```

Answer (score 1):

`+` operator has different meanings for different types. For `str` it is concatenation, for `int` add operation in math:

```
>>> 11 + 22
33
>>> "11" + "22"
'1122'
```

In your particular case try to use `int` everywhere where integer type variable is needed, and format output if necessary:

```
num_in = int(input("what + 33 is 44?: "))
set_num = 22 + 11

if num_in + set_num == 44:
    print("Yes!")
else:
    print("{} + {} is not 44.".format(num_in, set_num))
```